# Prompting of spaces before, in between or after insertion in SQL SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, trim

I have this SSIS which works well in Visual Stdio. But the only issue left is me going about letting it tell me if there is a space before, in between or after the inserted data in any column in the various tables. 
Example, consider the table below:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  Name  |            Description            |
---------------------------------------------
| Orange | "  a large round juicy citrus.."  |
| Orange | "A large round juicy citrus..  "  |
| Orange | "A large round juicy citrus..  "  |
| Orange | "A large round juicy citrus.."    |
| Orange | "A large    round juicy citrus.." |
---------------------------------------------
```

Notice in the description table, there are spaces before, in between or after the statements. I want my SSIS to tell me those spaces exist. I was thinking of an after insert trigger or cursor to check all records and tell me which table and column has that.

Counting your assistance guys. 
Thank you all.

Comment: If you want your SSIS package to tell you that, you won't use trigger on the table. Place a Script task on your package to check that in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by  replacing space with empty string in description column and then subtract lengths. If length >0 there is space present otherwise no.

```
select name
,description
, (Case when (len(description) - len(replace(description, ' ', ''))) >0
then 'Y' else 'N' end) space_YN
from tab;
```

Link to SQL fiddle:- 
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7cc6f/5)

Comment: Won't this replace spaces in the middle?

Comment: maybe instead of replace use ltrim

Comment: @KeithL:- OP want to check all spaces "Notice in the description table, there are spaces before, in between or after the statements".